# ENOSPC error on EC2 volume with 23G free disk space

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2

I recently ran out of disk space on my EC2 volume, causing my production application to crash. I expanded the volume using [this article](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-expand-volume.html), and running `df -H` shows the increased disk size:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       34G  9.7G   23G  30% /
```

However, I've just noticed that uploads to the server are failing. Checking the logs, I can see there are many of the following error:

```
Error: ENOSPC, write
```

This suggests I've ran out of disk space, but the `df` output above says I have 23G free. How can this be?

---

Update: `df -Ti` shows that I'm not running out of inodes:

```
Filesystem     Type  Inodes IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1     ext4 2097152 85074 2012078    5% /
```

Comment: Check whether you are running out of inodes rather than disk space by using "df -i". http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109349/why-does-the-linux-kernel-report-out-of-disk-space-when-in-reality-it-is-out-o mentions someone encountering this same problem, and explains why you get the saame error in both cases (running out of disk space, and out of inodes)

Comment: Thanks. I've added the output of `df -Ti` above. Seems I'm not running out of inodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebooted the instance and uploads started working again. Curiously some more partitions appeared which were not previously there:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       34G  9.7G   23G  31% /
udev            3.9G  8.2k  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           782M  173k  782M   1% /run
none            5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
none            4.0G     0  4.0G   0% /run/shm
```

Comment: Though answer is accepted, I really still don't understand what caused your problem. Was tmpfs out of space?